# Powershell - Array - How do I retrieve records from Import-csv and populate web page fields?

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, import, web

I'm using Powershell to read data from an imported csv file w/ headers and multiple records and then map those 'values' to populate a web form but can't get it to work

Part 1
 - how to read/input the fields into the web form for the first record?

Part 2
 - how to loop through to read the next record?

I'm fairly new to Powershell so I appreciate your help.

Contents of the File TxnArray.txt:

```
Date,Time,TxnNumber
14-Apr-2015,10 AM,1
14-Apr-2015,9 AM,2
```

Code:

```
#web site...


$TxnArray = Import-Csv c:\TxnArray.txt

while($ie.busy) {sleep 1} 

$ie.document.getElementById("TxnDate").value = $TxnArray[0]

$ie.document.getElementById("TxnTime").value = $TxnArray[1]

$ie.document.getElementById("TxnNumber").value = $TxnArray[2]

$ie.document.getElementById("Save").click()
```

Comment: PowerShell is not the right tool to create webpages. Can't you access your CSV data from a webpage using javascript? But if you insist, you need to access your values like this: $TxnArray[0].Date, $TxnArray[0].Time, $TxnArray[0].TxnNumber

Comment: Thanks - I'm actually trying to fill a form on the web page (not create it) - a poor mans 'TDD'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically need a `ForEach($x in $y)` loop. Something like:

```
ForEach($Entry in (Import-CSV C:\Path\To\File.CSV)){
    <code to navigate to form and wait for the page to be 'not busy'>
    $ie.document.getElementById("TxnDate").value = $Entry.Date
    $ie.document.getElementById("TxnTime").value = $Entry.Time
    $ie.document.getElementById("TxnNumber").value = $Entry.TxnNumber
    $ie.document.getElementById("Save").click()
}
```